# Some help with a proof for a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $g(x,y) = xyf(\frac{x+y}{xy})$, and let f be a differentiable single variable function. Prove that $g:=u$ is the solution to the following Partial Differential Equation:

$$\partial_x u x^2 - \partial_y u y^2 = G(x,y)u$$

Find G.

Now, what I got instead, was $\partial_x u (x^2-1) -\partial_y(y^2+1) = u(x-y+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y})$. I'm fairly new to PDEs so I'm not sure how to apply chain rule.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $g(x,y) = xy f(z(x,y)) = xy f((x+y)/xy)$ then $$g_{x} = \underbrace{\partial_{x}(xy) f + xy \partial_{x} f}_{\text{product rule}} = \partial_{x}(xy) f + xy \underbrace{\frac{df}{dz} \partial_{x} z}_{\text{chain rule}} = \partial_{x}(xy) f + xy \frac{df}{dz} \partial_{x} \left( \frac{x+y}{xy} \right) = \dots$$ Similarly for $g_{y}$.

Comment: I found out where my mistake was. Thank you!